# await a Event function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I need to wait inside a for loop untill a event function is called.
Im awaiting a response from a child process, that I'm creating with `let worker = cluster.fork();` 
I'm answering every child process with a special message within an array. so if the for loop continues without waiting i might send it the wrong data ( the data of the next device or so on).

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   if(connected_devices.includes(data[i].deviceID) == false) {
     let worker = cluster.fork();
     connected_devices.push(data[i].deviceID);
   }
   await worker.on('message', function (msg) { // wait untill this function is called then continue for loop
     worker.send({ device: data[i].deviceID, data[i].name});
   }
}
```

So my question is how can i wait untill my `worker.on()` function is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `worker.on` function is being called sequentially and completes. There is nothing asynchronous about `worker.on`. However, it is registering a function to be called by some other means, presumably, when the worker submits a message back to the cluster.

Details aside, the `worker.on` function submits the anonymous function to be called at a later time. If the concern is that the data being passed to that anonymous function might be affected by the iteration, then I think your code seems fine.

There may be an issue with how you are declaring the `worker` variable because it is defined in the enclosed scope of the `if` conditional. However, the code you are questioning should function like the below:

```js
// Stubs for woker.on and worker.send
const stubWorker = {
    on: (type, func) => {
        console.log('worker.on called');
        setTimeout(func, 1000);
    },
    send: (obj) => {
        console.log(`Object received: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
    }
};

const cluster = {
    fork: () => stubWorker
};

const data = [
    { deviceId: 0, name: 'Device Zero' },
    { deviceId: 1, name: 'Device One' },
    { deviceId: 2, name: 'Device Two' },
    { deviceId: 3, name: 'Device Three' }
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    // Removed if condition for clarity
    const worker = cluster.fork();

    worker.on('message', function () {
        worker.send({
            device: {
                id: data[i].deviceId,
                name: data[i].name
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, my worker processes only receive the data of the last iteration

Comment: What library/software are you using for your worker process?

Comment: I'm using Cluster for node.js
i got it to work now.
but i'm noticing some other weird behaviour. the iteration inside my worker.send function is unordered.
So it can be that my last child process is the first to send a message to my master process, somehow.
Sometimes the interation inside worker.on is like 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 and sometimes  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: To make a long story short: it works, the iterations are correct but i don't know how the iterations are saved? every child process gets called once, and gets the correct data. thanks for clearing things out